# How do I get notification when user clicks "forgot" on wifi access point

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to perform some task when user clicks on the "forgot" on connected wifi access point.

I checked for "isWifiConnected()" of the WifiManager , but its not allowing to perform my task.

Please help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

did you set wifi permissions in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: then you need to provide more info as to what you're actually doing.  What is a "forgot" button?

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine that it would be possible to hook the "Forget network" button for a Wifi network.

You could poll [`getConfiguredNetworks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks%28%29) at an interval, then compare the list from the last time you polled to the current list, and you can find the networks forgotten since you last checked.

If you provide more information about your situation and why you need to know when someone forgets a network, it might help.